# Объясните значение кода js

Tags: javascript

Недавно подошёл всерьёз к изучению js и я не мог даже предполагать, что он такой сложный и запутанный. Сейчас столкнулся с кодом, который интерпретировать хочу с Вашей помощью -

```
myModule.factory("TheService", function(TheObject) {
var service = function(obj) {
    this.obj = obj
}
```

А именно я не понимаю строчку -

```
this.obj = obj
```

я понимаю, что **this.obj**, это обращение к **obj** указанному в параметрах метода - ( в коде жирное выделение не работает, но звездочки я все равно не удалю, так понятней )

```
var service = function(**obj**) {
```

Но тогда что его значение?

Comment: это агрумент функции, значение, которое передаётся в функцию

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то когда метод выполнится, то свойство уже не будет obj уже не будет доступно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код вырван из какого-то контекста, поэтому тут приходится гадать, для чего он. Как вариант, прочитайте об области видимости в JS(вы будете удивлены) и ООП на прототипах в JS.

Ключевое слово this не относится к функции, поскольку области видимости заканчиваются на объектах, а не функциях. Поэтому this.obj не указывает на параметр, а указывает на объект, в котором эта функция будет выполнятся.

Вообще, слово this:

1. указывает на объект, в области видимости которого выполняется данный код.
2. используется совместно с ключевым словом new для ООП на прототипах

Например, если выполнить простой код:

```
a = 10;
(function(a){
    alert(this.a);
})(1);
```

То можно обнаружить, что слово this была ссылка на видимость объекта и вывела "10", вместо переданного в функцию "1". То же самое можно проделать так:

```
function service(obj){
    this.obj = obj;
}
service(10);
alert(window.obj); //выведет 10
```

Как ни странно, но слово this будет указывать на объект, в частности при простом случае это будет window и у него появится свойство obj. Если же выполнить эту функция с словом new:

```
function Service(param){
    this.param = param;
}
var service = new Service(10);
alert(window.param); //выведет undefined
alert(service.param); //выведет 10
```

То видно, что создался новый объект, на который как раз таки и указывала ссылка this при использование слова new вместе с ним.

Comment: @Alex Krass: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ! По сути это и есть весь код, вот только я ещё не привык, что этот код потом в общий встраивается.. Если честно, то мне очень тяжело язык дается. для меня диковато выглядит передача методов метод и анонимные функции..

Comment: @shatal, если в нем начать глубоко разбираться, то можно найти много неожиданного и довольно сложного. Могу лишь посоветовать Флэнагана, Стефанова и Джона Ресига почитать. Я начинал с ActionScript и поскольку они на одном стандарте, то JS при изучении уже можно сказать знал.

Comment: @Alex Krass: Спасибо за советы! Знаю что почитать нужно обязательно, чтобы сэкономить время, но к сожалению его сейчас нет, но в будущем я вернусь к этой теме, благо она от меня уже никуда не уйдет. Я тоже начинал с AS, но только с as3, который как небо и земля с js. Но Вы наверное с as2 начинали?

Comment: Да, я начинал с AS 2.0 и потом AS 3.0, хотя большинство из второго справедливо и для третьего. В третьем просто реализован переделанный ECMAScript 6, поэтому возможно когда-нибудь в JS тоже появятся классы вместо прототипов как в AS 3.0.